# How to perform operations on bound data referenced in a string

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to convert the slider's value from a decimal to 2 digit integer. Basically, I want to use :F2 to get it to just 2 decimal places and then multiply by 100. I cannot figure out how to multiply by 100 though.

How would I do this?

XAML:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference Slider},
                      Path=Value, 
                      StringFormat='Font Size: {0}'}"/>
<Slider x:Name="Slider"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to create a new value converter in the code and reference it as a static resource. This approach will enable any kind of conversion inside the code as well as any kind of parameter passed to the converter.

The following article describes how the ternary operator works in C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Hope it helps!

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SliderValueMultiplier x:Key="multiplier"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference Slider}, Path=Value,
                             Converter={StaticResource multiplier}, 
                             ConverterParameter=100}"></Label>
    <Slider x:Name="Slider"></Slider>
</StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
public class SliderValueMultiplier : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null) return 0;
        double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out double multiplier);
        return value != null ? Math.Round((double) value, 2) * multiplier : 0;        
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: the code is just an example of what your solution might look like. It should never be considered production ready without additional testing.*

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer. I was hoping there was an easier way to do this, like just adding a *100 somewhere to my code, but this isn't too bad. The only thing is that I don't understand the return value != null ? Math.Round((double) value, 2) * multiplier : 0;  line. I am unfamiliar with the question mark and the colon. This is probably a pretty basic question, but bc I am self taught there are a lot of holes in my programming knowledge. So if you could explain that line to me, that would be great. thank you

Comment: @user65909 The best way to figure out is to think like C# compiler here, you start from the very left. The `return` is perhaps simple, it defines what the method is returning. Next expression is called ternary conditional operator which has a boolean condition before the `?`, if that condition is true left expression after the `?` and before `:` is evaluated/returned and if the condition is false the right one, which is between the `:` and the `;`. You can read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It's concise if/else. Thank you very much for explaining.